# How to Turn iPad on?

Tags: ipad

I was watching a video on YouTube and my iPad just blanked out. I have tried charging it for one hour (like the Apple website said to), connecting it to iTunes and held the 'off/on' and the 'home' button together for a minute (roughly).

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5894688?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the **Off/On** and the **Home** buttons simultaneously until you see the Apple logo on the screen.